# handle emptylist and asynctask

Tags: android, listview

I use useful [guide](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=422) written by Cyril Mottier there empty state of `ListView` inflate in `ViewStub` with id `@android:id/empty`. In this method all good, but if i have `ListActivity` without attached Adapter via `setListAdapter` or attached empty Adapter then i see empty view. It's all clear but if i want realize logic like this:

1. Open `ListActivity`
2. Attach `adapter`
3. Execute `AcyncTask` and get data for `Adapter`, show progress dialog
4. Call notifyDataSetChanged
5. dismiss dialog

Then from 1 to 3 steps i look empty view with error (e.g. "not found"). But I want show error only after execute `AsyncTask`. While during executing `AsyncTask` i want show only process dialog. I try play around use visibility option of `@android:id/empty`, try use `include` in `xml`. But can't realize this logic. Any suggestion would appreciate.

**UPD**: More information
I have `activity.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@id/gd_action_bar_content_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        style="@style/listViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="false" />

     <ViewStub
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        layout="@layout/error" />

</FrameLayout>
```

error.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_cheese" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/no_cheese" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ListActivity Class:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener, OnItemClickListener{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity); //inflate activity with ViewStub
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, Collections.EMPTY_LIST); 
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    new SearchAndFill().execute("");
    }
}
```

And Async class:

```
private class SearchAndFill extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Object>>{
    LoadingDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (dialog==null){
            dialog = new LoadingDialog(MyListActivity.this);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Object> doInBackground(String... str) {
        return search(str[0]); //this is HTTP GET request
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Object> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        showResult(result); //this is fill adapter data and call notifyDataSetChanged
    }
}
```

When activity create and inflate `activity.xml` it's show empty with and then execute `AsyncTask`, while `AsyncTask` executing i see empty view. When call `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask` i see result of HTTP GET request. When activity creating and inflated `activity.xml` it's show empty with and then execute `AsyncTask`, while `AsyncTask` executing i see empty view. When call `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask` i see result of HTTP GET request. I think it's wrong. I want show blank ListView before AsyncTask executed, and after if result equals Collections.EMPTY_LIST i want show text with image (e.g nothing found)

Comment: please consider revising your question and maybe adding some code.  im finding it vary hard to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I understood this is what you want to achieve...

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener, OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity); //inflate activity with ViewStub
        ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_STUB_ID)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, Collections.EMPTY_LIST); 
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        new SearchAndFill().execute("");
    }
}

...    ...    ....

private class SearchAndFill extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Object>>{
LoadingDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    if (dialog==null){
        dialog = new LoadingDialog(MyListActivity.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected List<Object> doInBackground(String... str) {
    return search(str[0]); //this is HTTP GET request
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Object> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (result == null || result.size() == 0){
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_STUB_ID)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // add stuff to mAdapter here...
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: Even if I do not understand why you see the ViewStub at beginning, it is inflated when you change the visibility or you call explicitely infalte.

Comment: This comment is decisive, I noticed that if `viewstub` will have the `android:id = "@android:id/empty"`, it will automatically be visible on setContentView. Finally at least some movement. if you do as you are written in the answer, then everything works. but inflated ViewStub covers everything, even if data not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try setting text value of your empty view to empty string (`""`) then change the text value to error message when AsyncTask is complete.

Hope it solved your problem.